The Azure AD B2C custom policy call by JavaScript is not stored data in Power Page
Now, I want to set up a custom policy for sign-in and sign-up (separate flows) within Power Pages. Everything seems to be working fine, and the custom policy flow is functioning correctly (it can store the data properly). However, after completing the sign-up or sign-in flow, the custom policy redirects to the homepage. Unfortunately, the user data from the sign-up process is not being stored in the Power Pages Contact Table (but have stored inside the Azure AD B2C). I'm calling the custom policy using the MSAL browser JS because Power Pages only allows setting up one flow configuration (either sign-up combined with sign-in or any single flow). Below is my code for calling the custom policy:
 $("#SignUp").click(function(){
    acquireToken();
  });

  const msalConfig_signUp = {
    auth: {
      clientId: 'clientId',
      authority: 'https://yourtenant.com/b2c_1a_signup',
      knownAuthorities: ["yourtenant.b2clogin.com"],
      redirectUri: 'https://yourtenant.com/signin-aad-b2c_1',
    },
  };

  const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig_signUp);

  async function resetRedirect(){

    await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();

  }

  resetRedirect();

  async function acquireToken(){
    // Call the function to initiate token acquisition

     try {
       // Parameters for token request
       const request = {
           scopes: ['openid' , 'email'],
         };
 
         await msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(request);


     }  
     catch (error) {
       console.error('Error during token acquisition:', error);
     }
   }

I have only performed these specific actions without configuring anything else. Am I missing any crucial steps? If so, how can I resolve this issue?

Ensure Power Pages Contact Table is properly configured to receive data, check custom policy configuration for required attributes, handle token response to send data to the table after sign-up, and verify redirect handling to ensure user flow continuity.
